# Что делать, если у меня возник вопрос, который уже был задан, но ответ на него отсутствует?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, неотвеченные-вопросы

Прокомментировать вопрос (спросить, как автор решил свою проблему) - не могу (из-за отсутствия рейтинга), да и сам вопрос задан более полугода назад.
Сам вопрос - [Как организовать проверку типа прокси?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374177/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8)

P.S. Мне будет достаточно отделить `socks` от `http`, хотя от полного ответа, на поставленный по ссылке выше вопрос, я бы не отказался.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Есть много способов. Любой может сработать.

## Правильный способ

1. Заработать 75 репутации.
2. Потратить 50 репутации на конкурс.

Самый эффективный способ, потому что вопрос заметит больше всего пользователей.

## Приемлемый способ

1. Заработать 20 репутации.
2. Кинуть ссылку на вопрос в чате.

Относительно эффективный способ, потому что в чате сидят активные участники.

## Читерский способ

1. Заработать 5 репутации.
2. Скинуть ссылку на вопрос на Мете.

Собственно, что вы сделали. На Мету заглядывают самые активные участники, это способ привлечь их внимание.

## Неэффективный способ

1. Заработать 50 репутации.
2. Откомментировать вопрос.

Скорее всего, комментарий не заметит никто кроме автора. То есть у вас будет только один потенциальный отвечающий.

## Хитроумный способ

1. Не зарабатывать репутации.
2. Предложить хорошую правку вопроса.

Если правка будет принята, вопрос "апнется" и попадёт на главную странцу. Некоторые участники регулярно просматривают её, поэтому вопрос будет замечен.

## Неправильный способ

1. Не зарабатывать репутации.
2. Задать вопрос-дубль.

Вопрос прочитают. Скорее всего, закроют как дубль. Однако входящего трафика может хватить, чтобы кто-нибудь ответил на вопрос. Учтите, что активная ловля минусов и написание впоследствии закрываемых вопросов может привести к автоматическому бану.

## Сложный способ

1. Не зарабатывать репутации.
2. Задать вопрос-дубль, сослаться на старый вопрос, добавить достаточно деталей, чтобы не сочли дублем.

Если изначальный вопрос не содержит достаточно деталей, например, самостоятельных попыток решения, встреченных проблем, исследования проблемы в поисковиках и т. п., то можно включить это всё в свой вопрос. Это сильно снизит шансы на закрытие.

---

P. S. Вопрос определения типа прокси не должен возникать. Эта информация должна быть доступна изначально. Если вы от балды тыкаетесь в публичные прокси и надеетесь на удачу, то просто попробуйте подключиться всеми возможными способами.

Comment: На втором способе догадался, кто автор ответа :)

Comment: Учитывая то, что вопросы на Мете транслируются в чат, третий способ — улучшенная версия второго.

Comment: Мне нравится читерский способ. Отличное руководство, добавил в Community FAQ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Куда-куда?..

Comment: @Discord: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983/181472

Comment: Несогласен, что неправильный способ - неправильный. Я бы в такой ситуации закрывал старый вопрос как дубликат нового. Да и вообще, кто бы это вдруг вспомнил про старый вопрос, если на него даже не отвечали?

Answer (score 6):

Существует причина почему нельзя закрыть  вопрос как дубликат, если у него нет одобренных ответов.

Существует причина почему даже вопросы, помеченные дубликатами, не удаляются с сайта как многие другие закрытые вопросы.

Если у вас есть вопрос и вы не нашли существующего ответа, то *просто задайте свой вопрос.* Не нужно тень на плетень наводить.

То что вы озаботились начать обсуждение на Мете говорит, что приложив усилия, по качеству вы сможете задать вопрос лучше большинства вопросов на Stack Overflow — таких авторов стоит только приветствовать — это продвигает цели сайта: больше шансов что будет получен полезный ответ, больше шансов что смогут найти вопрос люди с похожей проблемой.

Убедитесь, что вы знакомы с:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Если так произошло что вы нашли уже заданный идеальный вопрос, который вы не можете улучшить, который при этом по загадочным обстоятельствам остался без ответа, то можно попробовать привлечь к нему внимание с помощью объявления конкурса. Публиковать ссылку в чате стоит только, если вы думаете вопрос может быть интересен участникам чата, а начинать обсуждение на Мете стоит только по Мета темам (об устройстве сайта, сообщества) за редким исключением.