# Конкурсный вопрос на Мете

Tags: поддержка, предложение, мета, конкурс

Некоторые вопросы на Мете хотелось бы как-то форсировать, но принятый на основном сайте механизм конкурсных вопросов тут не работает.

Почему бы не добавить такой функционал на Мету с возможностью черпать репу из основного профиля?

Как иначе можно стимулировать заинтересованность сообщества вопросом на Мете?

Comment: Платите модератору 500 репы, он вешает метку [meta-tag:важное]. )))

Comment: Чего так мало? Всё равно больше 20000 толку нет, только для виду.

Comment: Я бы отдал сколько-нибудь баллов репутации, чтобы назначить конкурс на этот вопрос, так как считаю, что ему уделили недостаточно внимания :)

Comment: В таком случае, как я понимаю, будут проблемы с переводом репутации. Например, по какой метке участник получил +репутацию из вопроса на мете? И стоит ли учитывать такие ответы в счётчиках знаков?

Comment: @NickVolynkin оказалось, что проще самому стать модератором.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что активные участники быстро поднимут такой вопрос в "Важное на Мете" или "Обсуждаемое на Мете", так что нет повода для поднятия вопроса при помощи затрат репутации.

Comment: Любой интересный вопрос поднимается активными участниками. Конкурс же нужен, в частности, как раз когда такого внимания не хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос на мете не получил внимания - это не значит, что он его уже его не получит. Есть способы изменить его судьбу.

#### Нормальные способы

- Кинуть ссылку на вопрос в [общий чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) и попросить кого-нибудь ответить.
- Позвать какого-то конкретного участника, (который, как вам кажется, может знать ответ на вопрос) в чате (@ИмяПользователя или создать отдельную комнату c пользователем) и попросить его ответить.
- Отредактировать вопрос...

  - если это ваше собственный вопрос, то добавьте туда больше информации и ссылок.
  - если это не ваш пост, то вы можете осуществить правку меток/орфографии и пунктуации. Такие правки сами по себе приветствуются.

> После правки вопрос поднимется на главную и есть шанс, что к нему будет какое-то внимание.

- Создать пост на MSE, если вопрос может охватывать не только ruSO.
  Иногда туда размещают даже те вопросы, которые связаны лишь с ruSO, если на локальной мете сообщество не в силах решить вопрос ([пример](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350905/if-a-user-copies-content-from-another-so-post-into-his-own-post-verbatim-is-the)). Кстати, на MSE есть метка [`russian-stackoverflow`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-stackoverflow).

#### Сомнительные способы

- [Поднятие вопроса с помощью бессмысленного редактирования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10966/). Это не запрещено и иногда даже уместно. Но часто так делать не надо.
- Задать на мете вопрос с метками [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91). Начать из далека и сделать вид, что задаёте мета-вопрос о чём-то, а в конце кидаете ссылку на вопрос. Таким образом вы создаёте отдельную дискуссию + привлекаете  внимание к своему вопросу. [Пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428).
- Если вопросу меньше двух недель, но на нём нет метки [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), так как она не подходит по смыслу - то всё равно повесить её на вопрос. Это нужно для того, чтобы дать вопросу шанс на попадание в "обсуждаемое на мете". Если нет ответов и комментариев мало - это не всегда беда. Я лично видел в "обсуждаемых" вопрос с 1 комментарием и без ответов. Нужно много голосов и просмотров.
- Если вы считаете, что вопрос **очень** важен всему сообществу здесь и сейчас - <kbd>тревога</kbd> -> <kbd>Требуется вмешательство модератора</kbd> и вводите следующий текст:

> Данный вопрос не получил внимания. Однако на данный момент о очень важен сообществу, потому что <причины>. Возможно, на него стоит повесить метку [важное], его увидит так больше людей.

Comment: Тревога, чтобы повесить "важное" для привлечения внимания - этот способ я бы точно исключил из "нормальных" и моментально перевел в "сомнительные".

Comment: @AntonMenshov но ведь [договорились](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12635/532877) же, что можно использовать тревогу, чтобы попросить модератора повесить [статус-завершено]. Почему тогда с другими красными метками  так нельзя?

Comment: на мой взгляд - тут огромная разница. Если вопрос не привлек внимания - значит скорее всего он точно не заслуживает тега "важное", и рекомендация ставить тревогу явно вредна (на мой взгляд). Исключения, наверное, возможны, но я с таким ни разу не сталкивался за все свое довольно долгое пребывание на SO.  С [статус-]ами все проще. Завершено - значит завершено. Задумано - значит задумано.

Comment: @AntonMenshov переместил в сомнительные.