# Поднятие вопроса путём бессмысленного редактирования

Tags: обсуждение

Насколько нормальна ситуация регулярного поднятия вопроса в списке путём его редактирования, не привнося, по сути, ничего нового? Должен ли модератор как-то прореагировать на такое поведение участника? Пример:

[image: поднятие вопроса]

А что если этим занимаются разные участники на одном и том же сообщении?

Вообще, на основном сайте есть конкурсы для поднятия вопросов и привлечения к ним дополнительного внимания. На Мете такого нет, а [хотелось бы порой иметь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4271/176217).

Comment: На мой взгляд, зависит от вопроса.

Comment: Стоит отредактировать этот вопрос, так как только в последнем предложении становиться ясно, что это именно про Мету

Comment: @Qwertiy раскройте вашу мысль, пожалуйста.

Comment: @4per не стоит. Вопрос не ставит своей целью получение ответа исключительно применительно к мете.

Comment: Лично я считаю такую ситуацию совершенно нормальной - при условии, что редактирование не заключается в добавлении фраз типа "скорее-быстрее-помираю-зачёт горит". А какие ещё есть способы поднять вопрос? особенно если уже по существу всё сказано, и всё дело в том, чтобы дождаться того, кто сможет ответить... Опять же - вот я, например, почти всегда пасусь на "Вопросы -> Новые", и мне от таких поднятий ни холодно ни жарко, ибо в этом вьюве они ни разу не поднимаются.

Comment: @Akina ну т.е. если я, например, после очередного такого бампинга вопроса буду делать аналогичное действие на других N вопросах (что неминуемо приведёт к проседанию первого в списке) - это тоже нормально? Или нормально только 1, а 2 и более - уже атата?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, вполне нормально. Только действие-то бессмысленное, "назло бабушке отморожу уши". Надолго тебя хватит этой фигнёй маяться - чужие вопросы поднимать исключительно ради чтобы поднять?

Comment: @edem не надо, пожалуйста, искажать смысл исходного сообщения.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в чём отличие?

Comment: @edem проверяющие != модераторы

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну исправил бы это слово.

Comment: @edem не надо ничего исправлять. Просто не надо ничего исправлять, если нет на то реальной необходимости. Об этом в том числе и сам текущий вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Ну тут можно с разных точек посмотреть...

- Никакого правила, которое бы это запрещало нет — модераторы банить не будут (кто-то помнит, что помешало забанить пони сразу???).
- Так, чисто, как просто участнику,  мне лично это не нравится. Так, конечно можно сделать (я так даже иногда делал), но тут должны ИМХО быть следующие моменты:

  1. Правка должна быть полезной (и желательно хоть чуть-чуть, но существенной). Если это так, то вообще это просто правка, ничего другого.
  2. Должен быть повод ;) Например: вопрос закрыли несправедливо, а надо привлечь внимание.

Ну и тогда это не что-то "противозаконное", а вполне себе нормальное действие.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Спасибо. Что-то мне два новых ответа одновреммено минусанули. Видимо кто-то мной недоволен ;)

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ой, я там просто написал, что кажется, что я имею в виду наоборот ;D

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем нормальна такая ситуация. Этот [топик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/377637) уже давно не актуален, никому не интересен, он не редактируется и не дополняется. Интересен он только лишь самому автору этого топика (@andreymal). Ранее я уже отмечал этот топик тревогой, однако она была отклонена, поэтому не совсем понятно, почему модераторами поощрялись(?) такие методы манипуляции поднятия вопросов, которые возможно и не описаны в правилах сообщества, но на мой взгляд являются нарушением, ну как минимум, простых человеческих правил поведения. И если это так, то как мне кажется, в таких случаях должны быть какие-то исключения из правил с целью рассмотрения этого вопроса на предмет нарушений. В любом случае каким-то образом на такое поведение модераторами реагировать нужно. В данный момент этот топик снова отмечен тревогой, и решение за модераторами. Считаю, что целью таких методов манипуляции является ни что иное как навязчивое навязывание автором топика своего личного мнения другим участникам сообщества.

Comment: «Этот топик уже давно не актуален» — он будет актуален до момента решения проблемы или до прекращения существования ruSO.

Comment: «выражает нетерпимость» — вам показалось, ничего подобного в комментарии нет. Разве что нетерпимость к нарушению вами правил — так это как раз хорошо и правильно, правила нужно соблюдать.

Comment: «навязыванием автором комментария своего личного мнения» — вам не кажется, что называть правила сайта «личным мнением» это, мягко говоря, перебор?

Comment: «такое грубое и аморальное поведение» — требование соблюдения правил это аморальное поведение? Утверждения подобного рода — это уже почти что экстремизм с вашей стороны.

Comment: Объвялять правила сайта, описанные в его справке, «личными» и «выдуманными» — это сильно.

Comment: @andreymal — прав. Н-да ваша ненависть к правилам подчас просто удивляет.

Comment: `навязчивое навязывание` — звучит не очень (тавтология). Может просто "навязывание"?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, да, тавтология, совершенно верно. Однако именно навязчивое. Это какая такая ненависть к правилам? Читаем внимательно правила к комментариям раздел `Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?`, там всё написано.

Comment: @Sevastopol' мой комментарий не попадает ни под один из пунктов «не следует»: он не предлагает мелкую правку, не отвечает на вопрос, не комплимент, конструктив, не обсуждение точек зрения и не обсуждает правила с политикой, а лишь исходит из уже существующих правил (а для их обсуждения к новой редакции комментария прикреплена ссылка на Мету, всё как положено.)

Comment: @Sevastopol' напротив, комментарий вполне попадает под пункты «когда стоит оставлять комментарий»: он (косвенно) просит автора уточнить вопрос (условия конкурса), высказывает конструктивную критику (почему конкурс слишком общий) и (в новой его редакции) в качестве дополнения имеет ссылку на Мету. Таким образом, **комментарий полностью соответствует правилам сайта и обязан присутствовать** пока он будет актуален. Любое его удаление или перенос в чат я буду рассматривать как превышение полномочий модераторами.

Comment: @Sevastopol' и при этом мне приходилось ставить много тревог на ваши комментарии-комплименты «прекрасным половинам человечества» и прочим, вот кому как не вам рассуждать об уместности комментариев, ага)))

Comment: @andreymal, об этом и речь, вы агрессивно настроены и выражаете нетерпимость. А это уже нарушение. Такое поведение просто опасно для сообщества в целом. Я к вам даже не обращался, а вы меня закидываете комментариями.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну предыдущий мой комментарий вполне можно удалить. И вообще все комментарии тут нужно удалить, и вторую половину ответа тоже, потому что они не по теме вопроса (я поставил соответствующую тревогу на ответ ещё вчера, но видимо Barmaley забывает заглядывать в очередь проверок на Мете:). Комментарий под псевдоконкурсом же полностью соответствует правилам сайта и должен присутствовать, а то, что вы в конструктивной критике видите агрессию и нетерпимость, — это уже ваши личные проблемы восприятия. Видимо, вас вообще можно только нахваливать.

Answer (score -2):

Я лично, как модератор и как просто многолетний участник данного *шоу* - не вижу в этом никакого преступления. И де юре (с точки зрения соблюдения формальных правил сообщества) и по-людски — не вижу в этом ничего аморального и противоестественного.

Comment: То есть если, допустим, кто-то будет каждую минуту все свои неотвеченные вопросы вот так поднимать (допустим, не ботом, а руками), то это нормально? Сомневаюсь.