# Почему удален вопрос с ответом? ("Как нарисовать и анимировать символ российского рубля")

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

Вопрос [Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F) вместе с развернутым ответом удалены *"участниками Barmaley♦"*. Хотелось бы знать причину удаления. Вероятно, она должна быть очень веская?

> Повторюсь, вопросы создавать сложно, интересные — практически
> невозможно. На мой взгляд, хорошие вопросы, которые не соответствуют
> правилам сайта из за отсутствия двух-трех слов в заключительном
> предложении закрывать или минусовать точно не стоит, как минимум, из
> за уважения к труду автора. Единственное верное решение — внести
> улучшающую правку.
> ...
> Давайте бороться «за», а не «против»! Создать
> базу знаний русскоязычного сообщества можно только вместе, работая
> сообща.
>
> Nicolas Chabanovsky♦

Так вот, это самое уважение я на ruSO нутром прочувствовал.

Comment: А надо было выбирать Victor VosMottor ;) (говорю прям как Грунди)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor если бы Вас можно было выбрать, то выбрали бы (я точно)

Comment: @EOF спасибо ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос восстановлен. Был удален из-за нескольких тревог на вопросе (уже не вспомню какими).

Исправляюсь.

**Update**

Тревоги были примерно такого содержания:

> Вы долб***лись? Этот псевдоконкурс «по своему индивидуальному сценарию» не соответствует правилам сайта по причине слишком общей формулировки, его надлежит незамедлительно отменить и закрыть.

> Вопрос с формулировкой «...и по своему индивидуальному сценарию» явно должен быть закрыт как слишком общий, а конкурс — отменён. Я надеюсь, новые модераторы уважают правила сайта?

и т.д. - там их было несколько.

Согласен, что удаление было неверным. Если не нравится вопрос - есть downvoting - этого достаточно. Мне лично вопрос тоже не нравится (если что).

Comment: А теперь закрываем псевдоконкурс.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос восстановлен.

Да, спасибо. Просто хотел сказать СПАСИБО, за справедливость.

> Мне лично вопрос тоже не нравится (если что).

А разве он должен нравится или нет? Это просто работа. Пусть и легкая, несложная, но работа. Для кого-то она может быть полезна. Не в смысле как нарисовать на CSS наш рубль. А просто как наипростейший пример рисования, анимации.

*Всё что я здесь делаю и выкладываю на ruSO, включая все ответы, я это делаю не для себя. И в свободное от работы время. Я умею всё это, и практика/опыт/знания у меня многолетние (как и у многих здесь участников), и проектов готовых за много лет уже сотни. И понты различные мне ни к чему, всё это мы уже проходили. Это всё для новичков, поэтому и прошу уважения к себе и к своей работе. Благодарю.*

Comment: Уважать работу по добавлению вредительских вопросов в базе знаний, наверное, всё-таки не очень правильно.

Comment: «наипростейший пример рисования, анимации» всегда можно найти в соответствующих учебниках. Даже если абстрагироваться от вредительства в базе знаний — работа всё равно бесполезная.

Comment: Андрей, вредительство - это [https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10966/377637](Поднятие вопроса путём бессмысленного редактирования). А вот любая работа, которая может являться пусть и маленьким примером, не может быть бесполезной. Ну как минимум один человек обязательно найдется, который откроет для себя что-то новое, или просто возьмет идею. И вот только ради этого уже стоит что-то делать.

Comment: В [свалке из бессвязных примеров анимации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370) никто ничего толкового не найдёт — и даже сами эти примеры никто не найдёт, потому что они «замаскированы» за всякими там знаками рубля и словами stackoverflow. Нужно не просто вбросить пример и забыть, а ещё и в подробностях разъяснить, что как и зачем применяется, какая задача решается, какие инструменты используются — для этого есть учебники, а для рассмотрения какого-то отдельного узкого аспекта или идеи, не вписывающихся в формат учебника, есть база знаний в формате вопрос-ответ.

Comment: Вы же просто замусориваете базу бессвязными неиндексируемыми примерами, что я всегда воспринимал и буду воспринимать как вредительство. И очень жаль, что вы этого не понимаете.

Comment: И самое парадоксальное — вы ведь умеете писать [нормальные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083483) [конкретные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667984) [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086490) про ту же анимацию, но на псевдоконкурсах вас почему-то переклинивает.

Comment: Андрей, извините, но мы друг друга, к сожалению, никогда не поймем, это напрасная дискуссия и пустая трата времени. Потому что разговариваем мы с вами на разных языках. Мой язык это HTML+CSS+JS+JQ+Помощь_новичкам_в_примерах. Вашего языка увы я не знаю.

Comment: Правила сайта работают одинаково для всех и независимо от понимания кого-либо кем-либо — псевдоконкурсы должны быть закрыты. (Или исправлены улучшающей правкой, но вы такой вариант почему-то принципиально не рассматриваете)

Comment: Открывается портал в адЪ :)

Comment: Приглашаю всех [на дискуссию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f)