# Ban-hammer против @Sevastopol'

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка, модераторский-произвол

Смотрю на 1 [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11134/%D0%A1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) в «Обсуждаемое на Мете» и вижу, что его автор — [@Sevastopol'](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/377637/sevastopol) — был забанен, хотя ещё несколько дней назад я видел его репутацию.

Какая причина этого бана? В этом мире просто так ничего не происходит.

---

Оказывается, ещё и [@andeymal](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) был забанен, ну его-то (вроде) понятно за что, а вот с [@Sevastopol'](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/377637/sevastopol) мне ситуация не ясна.

Comment: ["Для успокоения участников дискуссии" (с) Barmaley](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11153#comment47344_11153)

Comment: Они прям вообще наверно успокоились ;)

Comment: [tag:модераторский-беспредел] номер два

Comment: @VictorVosMottor спасибо, что закинули по ссылке меня не на мету, а на ruSO (а я думаю, почему это ссылка красная)

Comment: @return сорри перепутал

Comment: @VictorVosMottor [для вас](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB)

Comment: кота Леопольда на Вас всех нет :) как ни загляну тут опять драма

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ипатьева на нас нет)

Answer (score 13):

После [этого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11153/15479) его забанили,

> Чтобы дать участнику успокоиться

Подобное вообще не приветствуется на Мете. Вопросы должны быть обезличены. Если проблема в модерации, то нужно писать в общем, а не про конкретных людей. Если прям очень горит от конкретного модератора, то есть контактная форма.

Ну и там явный нападки в адрес обычных участников, что тоже свою роль сыграло.

С andeymal они часто в комментариях ругались, видимо, из-за этого в бан на отдых оба и отправились.

Comment: по-моему бан — это слишком жёстко

Comment: @return да нет. Нормальная практика — дать несколько дней бана, чтобы успокоились. Правда, в их случае это вряд ли поможет, т.к. конфликту уже почти год.

Comment: после бана у них не будет больше злости на модераторов?

Comment: @return если не забанить, то они продолжили бы нагнетать. А так есть шанс, что обдумают свои действия.

Comment: выбрали лучший из худших методов. хотя справедливости ради, я и сам не знаю, какой метод мог бы быть получше. может просто создать для них закрытую комнату для спаринга? не знаю

Comment: @return они свой спор не смогут решить. Там нужно решение со стороны.

Comment: Но вопрос на время бана не был ни удалён, ни закрыт. Чёт подозрительно.

Comment: @vp_arth модераторы троллят нас (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf, а что, если Севастополь = Бармалей? Вот где интрига)

Comment: @vp_arth нужно больше кукловодов!

Comment: Бан за жалобу на мете (вполне обоснованную) - это как-то совсем странно. Бан за необезличенность жалобы - ещё страннее.

Comment: @PashaPash это стало последней каплей, мне думается. До этого во многих обсуждениях на Мете они ругались.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik да без разницы, не может обоснованная жалоба стать последней каплей. Иначе все флагальщики уже б давно в бане сидели.

Comment: @PashaPash одно дело флагать (видно только ромб-составу), и совсем другое - публично выяснять отношения.

Comment: @PashaPash за флаги Бармалей уже грозился забанить людей)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну если модсостав на флаги не реагирует - что делать? тем более есть автоснос комментов по ключевым словам, и не факт, что модсостав эти флаги вообще видит.

Comment: Бан — признание модератора в неспособности разрешить спор. Бан ещё никогда не приводил к разрешению конфликта. Заткнуть рот человеку — худшее, что можно сделать в споре.

Comment: @VladD худшее — это пустить всё на самотёк и наблюдать как разгорается пожар.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Пустить на самотёк плохо, нужно разрешить конфликт. Бан не разрешает конфликт, он только делает видимость отсутствия конфликта. Ну это всё равно как если болит живот, не ехать к хирургу, а выпить побольше обезбаливающего. Симптомов нет, проблемы нет.

Comment: @VladD это как если бы при температуре выше 38 человек выпил парацетамол в ожидании врача.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ваша аналогия была бы хорошей, если бы модератор не был тем самым врачом. Продолжая аналогию, у нас получается, что врач выписывает парацетамол, а когда не помогает, выписывает дозу побольше. При простуде это работает. А если болит живот, то не совсем.

Comment: @VladD тут всё крутится вокруг доверия к модераторам. Если доверия нет, то любые их действия будут восприняты негативно)

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ну сейчас мы обсуждаем не _любые_ действия, а очень любимый _некоторыми модераторами_ бан как единственный способ разрешения конфликтов и споров. В такой ситуации доверие теряется очень быстро. И давайте не сваливать на юзеров ответственность за непрофессиональные действия модераторов и причинённый ими вред.

Comment: @VladD да я не сваливаю. Меня в данном случае больше интересует, какие именно модераторы принимали участие в бане (¬‿¬)

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, бан обоих участников был справедлив.

Sevastopol опубликовал несколько вопросов, нарушающих правила сообщества (слишком общих), а после того, как ему указали на это, проигнорировал претензии по существу и начал заявлять об [атаках на него](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11134/240512). На деле же никакой атаки не было, преобразование вопроса в общий - обычный модераторский инструмент, суть которого в ограничении обесценивания репутации. Оно не удаляет сведения об авторстве; если вклад первоначального участника остается наибольшим, рядом с общим сообщением также будет отображаться его имя. Его применение здесь было неэффективно, но атакой оно не являлось. Администрация заявила довольно четко, что на сайте следует соблюдать формат, в том числе в конкурсах: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10374/240512. Сообщество поддержало это заявление (рейтинг 17 против <=8 у других ответов). Если и администрация, и сообщество, и модераторы требуют соблюдать правила, этому следует подчиниться. Отрицание правил - вполне основание для бана. Правда, бан должен был сопровождаться закрытием проблемных вопросов, но здесь этого почему-то не было сделано.

Что до andeymal, то да, тут все понятно, обычный бан за недружелюбие. Называть другого участника "вредителем" недопустимо, это подпадает под пункт "Никаких резких замечаний или враждебно настроенных фраз" из норм поведения. andeymal повелся на провокацию, и это плохо, так как это еще один повод сторонников неформатных конкурсов выставить себя угнетаемыми.

Comment: Ваш ответ отмечаю тревогой, потому как он в отношении меня является набором обвинений, ничем не подтвержденный.

Comment: @Sevastopol', раз уж тут все высказывают свои мнения, то пусть высказывают. Удалять какие-то из них по любым причинам - уже попахивает цензурой, которая в этой теме явно неуместна, поэтому тревогу отклоняю.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight впрочем, предполагать, что бан был как-то связан с преобразованием вопроса в общий и постом на мете на эту тему - довольно странно и необоснованно.

Comment: @Qwertiy а есть ли вообще возможность внести правки в правила ruSO (путём голосования, например) относительно данных ситуаций, чтобы в будущем они хоть как-то регламентировались?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, я что-то даже не пойму, о каких ситуациях идёт речь. В принципе, всё можно обсудить и подумать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ответ будет немного в стороне от вопроса, но всё-таки, я тоже хотел бы высказать своё мнение.

Мы, участники ruSO, находимся на довольно большой площадке. Поскольку я на данном ресурсе не очень давно, всей истории данной ситуации (конфликта @andeymal и @Sevastopol' ?) я не в курсе, но даже за небольшой промежуток я уже успел наблюдать какие-то тёрки между вышеупомянутыми участниками. Я не знаю, кто из них прав, кто виноват, и знать не хочу. Однако, хочу заметить, что по моему мнению, бан двоих вышеупомянутых участников с формулировкой "чтобы успокоились" в корне не верен. Это самый настоящий модераторский произвол. Почему? Потому, что данная формулировка имеет довольно размытые грани, а это означает, что с такой формулировкой могут забанить кого угодно и почти за что угодно. А это уже может привести к довольно печальным последствиям для сообщества.

Так уважаемые модераторы, давайте не будем раздавать баны как листовки на проспекте. Если и банить, то за дело. Оскорбил, нарушил правила сайта - пусть отвечает по правилам SO. Нет? Так и на каком основании тогда выдавать бан.

Comment: "Чтобы успокоится" - это одна из стандартных формулировок о бане. Там произвольный текст ввести нельзя, насколько я знаю, модератор выбирает из списка стандартных, среди других, например, "За нарушения при голосовании" , "За низкокачественное содержимое".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight всё так. Модераторы не могут текст выбирать. По крайней мере, не помню такого.

Comment: одна из стандартных формулировок? мда, весело конечно

Answer (score -5):

Предлагаю разобраться, насколько правомерным было решение о блокировании учетной записи участника @Sevastopol'. Отбросив все эмоции, не будем зацикливаться на справедливости принятия такого решения. Важнее прояснить ситуацию, понять и постараться выяснить истинные намерения и причины блокирования участника. И как мне кажется, эти причины должны быть вескими и обоснованными. Подойдем к этому вопросу более детально и попробуем разобраться с некоторой терминологией.

Вот личное сообщение модератора с указанием причины блокирования учетной записи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Итак:

> Просьба успокоиться и обдумать свое поведение.

Из сообщения не совсем понятно, почему у модератора сложилось такое мнение, что участник @Sevastopol' не спокоен. Также не совсем понятно, о каком поведении идет речь. Интересно, чем модератор руководствовался и по каким признакам можно было всё это определить? Как мне кажется, для того, чтобы определить у человека степень его спокойствия или беспокойства, необходимо иметь высшее образование в области психологии, а также быть высококлассным специалистом, чтобы дистанционно оценить состояние человека. В нашем модераторском составе имеются такие специалисты? Думаю, что нет. Получается, что это просто какое-то абстрактное мнение, которое не имеет за собой никакого веского обоснования, и является ложным обвинением в адрес участника. Более того, в какой-то степени это можно расценить даже как унижение чести и достоинства личности, потому что другими словами это может пониматься следующим образом: "*закрой рот, меня не устраивает твоя позиция*".

> Ваши последние сообщения и посты имеют признаки агрессии по отношению
> к другим участникам.

Признаки агрессии - что это такое? Почитаем определение. Итак, *агрессия – это определенный вид действий, направленный на причинение морального или физического ущерба другим людям, это нападение на них с целью причинения вреда*. В сообщении в качестве примера приводится [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11153/377637), заданный участником @Sevastopol', где он якобы проявляет агрессию по отношению к другим участникам. Если внимательно прочитать текст вопроса, то становится очевидно, что в нем какие-либо признаки агрессии со стороны автора полностью отсутствуют. Напротив, я вижу в тексте этого вопроса жалобу на агрессию со стороны других участников в отношении автора вопроса и призыв к участникам сообщества не проявлять эту самую агрессию. Другие примеры сообщений или постов, где участник якобы проявлял агрессию, не приводятся. И здесь снова мы видим необоснованное обвинение в адрес участника, что само по себе также является унижением чести и достоинства личности.

Вот выдержка из [пояснительного комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11153/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%90-%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5#comment47373_11153) модератора @Barmaley к сообщению о блокировании учетной записи:

> это не бан (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем
> и нам и вам.

Судя по комментарию, уважаемый участник-модератор @Barmaley считает всех участников неспокойными. В том числе и себя. И по всей видимости, оценивая свое психологическое состояние таким образом, он это чувствует. Так вот, если для успокоения, по его мнению, необходимо блокирование учетной записи, то почему же он не заблокировал в том числе и свою учетную запись? Если это технически невозможно, то почему он не попросил другого модератора, чтобы тот заблокировал его учетную запись?

Логику же написанного до запятой мне понять трудно. Но думается мне, что это издевка. @Anton Menshov [задал совершенно справедливый вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11178/377637). И ему за это отдельное спасибо. Очень надеюсь, что мы получим хоть какое-то вразумительное разъяснение этого загадочного выражения.

---

Подводя итог, можно сделать следующий вывод. Оснований для блокировании учетной записи участника @Sevastopol' по крайней мере я не увидел. Напротив же, прослеживается последовательное давление на участника, что само по себе является агрессией в отношении его со стороны модератора @Barmaley. Так полагать есть все основания. Сначала [удаляются вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11090/377637). После этого [вопросы отмечаются общими против воли его автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11134/377637). А теперь вот блокируется учетная запись участника по надуманным на то причинам.

К сожалению, как оказалось, участники сообщества полностью беззащитны против возможного подобного давления со стороны модератора, в руках которого находятся все инструменты, с помощью которых он себя чувствует царём и Богом и не считает нужным вдаваться в детали с целью разобраться в ситуации, прежде чем вынести вердикт, что напоминает средневековье, а не демократическое цивилизованное общество. И в некоторых таких руках это может быть очень даже опасно.

P.S. Кстати, для примера приведу признак (!возможной) агрессии: "*Вы мне, гады, еще за Севастополь ответите!*" (цитата из к/ф Брат).

Всех неравнодушных благодарю за поддержку, для меня это очень важно. Всем желаю успехов и надежной защиты!

Comment: стоп, как вы смогли прочитать сообщение от участника @Sevastopol', если оно личное? вы что, взломали его аккаунт? :)

Comment: Со всем уважением, конечно. Но если трезво поглядеть на ваш ответ - то это солянка из пассивной агрессии и демагогии. Вам сказали "ты не прав", а вы отвечаете "давайте проведем непредвзятый лексикографичесий анализ из которого узнаем, что я прав а модераторы психологичеси неустойчевые". Я не хочу покрывать модераторов, но полезность или информативность вашего ответа нулевая. Отписываюсь только чтобы пояснить, за что поставил минус.

Comment: @tym32167, да, совершенно верно, частично это демагогия. Мне настолько было непонятным решение о блокировании, высосанное из пальца, что по правде сказать, кроме как разжевать каждое его предложение, другого ничего не пришло. А агрессии нет, у меня ее нет совсем, даже когда заблокировали, поверьте мне, были только вопросы, и ничего больше. За минус вам спасибо. И скорее даже за правду, это ваша правда. А правда у каждого своя.

Answer (score -8):

У меня возникли некоторые сомнения и вопросы к [ответу участника @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11157/377637). Хотелось бы, с его позволения, отдельно прокомментировать определенные его спорные, на мой взгляд, моменты:

> Вопросы должны быть обезличены. Если проблема в модерации, то нужно
> писать в общем, а не про конкретных людей.

В [тексте вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11153/377637) никакие имена не указываются. Имена фигурируют на скриншоте комментариев. Но как мы знаем, любое графическое изменение скриншота будет являться нарушением авторских прав. Поэтому мы не можем эти скриншоты каким-либо образом видоизменять. Кроме этого, вопросы, ответы, комментарии находятся в открытом доступе, и их цитирование с указанием авторства никогда не запрещалось, а наоборот только поощрялось.

> С andeymal они часто в комментариях ругались

Это не совсем так. Обратимся за помощью к определениям. *Ругань - это слова, которыми ругают, сквернословие. Ругаться - это произносить грубые, оскорбительные, бранные слова.* Читая переписку между участниками, не сложно понять, что между ними нет никакой ругани. Исключением являются лишь последние пару комментариев одного из участников. Подчеркну: одного из участников.

> ...видимо, из-за этого в бан на отдых оба и отправились

Следовательно, если участник @andeymal отправился на отдых из-за ругани, то у меня возникает резонный вопрос: из-за чего тогда на отдых отправился участник @Sevastopol'?

Comment: Оба из-за нападок в адрес друг друга. То, что в сообщениях не использовался мат, роли мало играет. Подобные конфликты в целом негативный фон повышают. Был ли бан обоснован в этом случае — не мне судить. Я бы сначала попытался в личке связаться с обоими участниками.

Comment: Да замазать на скриншотах можно было

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, но тогда это уже можно было бы расценивать как нарушение авторских прав. А если так не считать, то это будет ни что иное как те же двойные стандарты.

Comment: @Sevastopol', зачем вы указывете определение, которое удобно вам? Есть ещё и вот такое: _"вести с кем-либо разговор, высказывая упрёки в грубом тоне и с использованием грубых выражений"_.

Comment: @Zhenyria, это словарь указывает такое определение.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вы наверное взяли определение с викисловаря? Но там есть и вторая дефиниция.

Comment: @Zhenyria, Большая советская энциклопедия, печатное издание 1926 года :)