# Проведение конкурсов анимации на Мете

Tags: обсуждение

В обсуждении  правил, организации и проведения конкурсов анимации, есть мнения, что их нужно проводить на Мете.

В связи с этим хочу уточнить некоторые детали:

**1. Какие метки нужно выбирать для конкурсов?**

[обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [дефект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) [локализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)[поддержка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0) [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b)[ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b)

Все метки имеют описание, в которых рассматриваются правила и технические проблемы сайта

С натяжкой можно выбрать метку  [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
Но она, как и все другие метки на Мете включает топики (их всего три) по обсуждению правил проведения, но не само, собственно соревнование.

На SO есть тоже метка [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) 35 - топиков. В них уже ответы с кодом программ на поставленный вопрос.

Конечно можно продублировать на Мете метки: [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) [jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg) именно те метки, по которым  и проводятся конкурсы  анимации.
Интересно, что мы напишем в описании метки на Мете [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css): обсуждение правил CSS?
Ну это по крайней мере, как-то несерьезно.

### Откуда берется репутация на вознаграждение при открытии конкурса на Мете?

Я правильно понимаю, что вознаграждение будет вычтено из общей репутации для обоих сайтов: Мета и Stackoverflow?
Но голоса за вопросы и ответы начисляются по **1 баллу** и не входят в общий рейтинг участника.

**То есть при организации конкурсов на Мете игра будет в одни ворота.**
Репутация будет вычтена из общего рейтинга, но не может быть частично компенсирована хорошими вопросами, ответами.

Кому будет интересны эти конкурсы? Организатору конкурса, отвечающим?

***Вопрос один, какая существует веская причина, предложения проведения и перевода конкурсов анимации на Мету?***

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117272/discussion-on-question-by-alexandr-tt-----).

Answer (score 4):

Такие конкурсы должны проводиться на основном сайте. Нет совершенно никаких оснований проводить их на мете. И к накрутке репутации они никакого отношения не имеют, поскольку для ответ на такие вопорсы требуется затратить довольно много времени и вполне логично, что оно окупается репутацией.

Comment: Кратко и по делу. Двумя руками за

Answer (score 3):

В первую очередь хочу сослаться на предысторию по теме: [Вопросы конкурсы, нужны/не нужны, можно/нельзя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11097/176217). Почему-то непосредственно в вопросе не увидел у вас ни одной ссылки на прежние связанные обсуждения.

Теперь по сути. На Мета сайтах (кроме [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) механизма конкурсов не предусмотрено. Есть соответствующее предложение на нашей Мете [Конкурсный вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4271/176217), но сомнительно, что что-то может по этому поводу измениться. Поэтому не стоить пытаться "натянуть сову на глобус".

Следующий момент, что на Мете ruSO вообще не надо писать о чём-то, что не относится к жизнедеятельности самого сайта Stack Overflow на русском. Проведение конкурсов или иных вопросов по анимации, трепанации, компиляции и т.д. тут быть не должно, если это так или иначе не связано с функционированием ruSO. Собственно поэтому прикрыли [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) - [Прекратить [диалоги-о-работе] на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/176217).

Т.о. т.к. проведение конкурсов на Мете невозможно в силу технических обстоятельств, а вопросы, не связанные с функционированием самого сайта будут являться офтопиком тут, то получить какую-то конкретику на вопросы по меткам, репутации и т.д., связанные с самой идеей, озаглавленной как "Проведение конкурсов анимации на Мете" не представляется возможным и в принципе необходимым.

Возможная причина предложения о переносе чего-либо на Мету - это, как мне кажется, в первую очередь желание прикрыть репутационную лазейку, т.е. получение автором лёгкой репутации на сайте.

В сухом остатке: конкурсы, связанные с тематикой сайта, должны быть на основном сайте. Если по той или иной причине они не будут соответствовать текущим правилам (онтопику) или не понравятся участникам сообщества, то будут минусоваться/закрываться/удаляться. Но даже если понравятся, следующее слово за модераторским составом. К сожалению, активность модераторов в плане разрядки обстановки на сайте на текущий момент вызывает озабоченность.

Comment: `Возможная причина предложения о переносе чего-либо на Мету - это, как мне кажется, в первую очередь желание прикрыть репутационную лазейку, т.е. получение автором лёгкой репутации на сайте`  А с чего вообще люди взяли, что программирование анимации легкая работа? Все, кто ратуют за запрещение анимаций специалисты в этой области? На подготовку конкурсов анимации я трачу, как минимум неделю. Прорабатываю и вопрос и ответ не  умозрительно, а в конкретном коде.

Comment: С какой стати переносить конкурсы анимаций на Мету, если она даже не приспособлена для этого? Я поэтому и задал такой вопрос о проведении конкурсов на Мете, чтобы сторонники этого задумались о технических возможностях таких действий.

Comment: *`"В сухом остатке: конкурсы, связанные с тематикой сайта, должны быть на основном сайте."`* -- стоило бы вытащить в начало ответа