# Что делать если мой вопрос "забыли"?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

У меня есть вопрос: [Чем больше надо вывести, тем дольше виснет sublime text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1527883/)

Его, можно сказать "забыли" то есть на нём только 2 комментария и больше ничего.

Как мне узнать ответ на мой вопрос, как обратить внимание на него?

Comment: для привлечения внимания к вопросу можно назначит конкурс. Также, каждое редактирование выводит вопрос на главную страницу

Comment: С метой вот [сложнее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4271/176217).

Comment: Ничего не делать. Иногда на очень старые вопросы прилетают ответы. Главное — не удалять.

Comment: Наверное, самое главное тут, понять, почему данный вопрос никому не интересен? Далее можно сделать выводы и скорректировать свои действия

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428/10105