# Можно ли как-то обновить заданный вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Подскажите, можно ли как-то обновить заданный мною вопрос, не задавая его повторно, дабы его увидело большее количество человек? Очень важная проблема, без решения которой не могу никак двигаться дальше.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429/220571

Answer (score 5):

Редактирование вопроса "поднимет" его. Но это плохая практика.

Когда у вас будет достаточно репутации, наилучшим способом привлечь внимание к вопросу будет объявление конкурса с наградой.

Comment: можно добавить, что привлекая внимание можно не только получить ответ, но и получить кучу минусов и вообще закрытый вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy а если бы кое-кто был модератором, то и бан.

Comment: можно добавить, что привлекая внимание можно не только получить ответ, но и получить кучу плюсов и вообще привлечь чужую награду на свой вопрос.

Comment: можно добавить, что если правка вопроса делает его (гораздо) лучше, то это нужно делать обязательно и только приветствуется